# Pig: Join with different field names

Tags: json, join, apache-pig, left-join

I have a set of tweets where I want to calculate the number of replies a user got using Pig.

My pig script looks like (Assuming y1 has the required json):

```
y2 = GROUP y1 BY in_reply_to_user_id_str;
y3 = FOREACH y2 GENERATE group AS in_reply_to_user_id_str, COUNT(y1) AS number_of_replies_to_user;
y4 = FOREACH y3 GENERATE in_reply_to_user_id_str, number_of_replies_to_user;
y5 = JOIN y1 BY user_id LEFT OUTER, y4 BY in_reply_to_user_id_str;
STORE y5 INTO '$DATA_OUTPUT' USING JsonStorage()
```

Now, my output looks like:

```
{"y1::user_id":"9642792"............"y4::in_reply_to_user_id_str":"9642792","y4::number_of_replies_to_user":1}
```

Whereeas I was expecting something like:

```
{"user_id":"9642792"..............."number_of_replies_to_user":1}
```

I donot want the alias names `y1` and `y5`. I deleted some unwanted fields that are not required to answer the question, just to make it more readable.

How can I do that? My Pig version (0.15) does not support `$0..`.

Also, is there a better way of calculating this value? SQL seems very straight forward but Pig is really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional step to generate the fields you need from y5 and then store the resulting y6 relation

```
y5 = JOIN y1 BY user_id LEFT OUTER, y4 BY in_reply_to_user_id_str;
y6 = FOREACH y5 GENERATE y1::$0,y1::$1,y1::$2,..........y4::$0,y4::$1;
STORE y6 INTO '$DATA_OUTPUT' USING JsonStorage();
```

Comment: Did not test it, but would expect something like `y1::userid AS userid`. How does the code in this answer specify what the fieldname should be?